# Executing queries in console script

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm struggling to figure out why the session I'm getting after pyramid's bootstrap is refusing to execute queries, raising the `transaction.interfaces.NoTransaction` exception.

I'm trying to create a script using the pyramid configuration, but working on a background task. I'm using the `bootstrap` function to get the environment in place. One of the approaches I tried was:

```
from pyramid.plaster import bootstrap

with bootstrap(sys.argv[1]) as env
    dbsession = env['request'].dbsession

    with dbsession.begin_nested():
        res = dbsession.execute('''SELECT ....''')
        ...
```

That creates a `SessionTransaction` as expected, but still raises a `NoTransaction`.

How can I initialise the connection, so I can access it as I normally do in the views?

Answer (score 3):

As described in https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/3219 the transaction is not initialised by default. It can be done using:

```
with bootstrap(sys.argv[1]) as env:
    with env['request'].tm:
        dbsession = env['request'].dbsession
        dbsession.execute(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `pyramid.plaster.bootstrap`. However, you could use the same template as the script that is auto generated when you create a new project using the `alchemy` template.

```
pcreate -t alchemy myproject
```

The script looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import transaction

from pyramid.paster import (
    get_appsettings,
    setup_logging,
    )

from pyramid.scripts.common import parse_vars

from ..models.meta import Base
from ..models import (
    get_engine,
    get_session_factory,
    get_tm_session,
    )
from ..models import MyModel


def usage(argv):
    cmd = os.path.basename(argv[0])
    print('usage: %s <config_uri> [var=value]\n'
          '(example: "%s development.ini")' % (cmd, cmd))
    sys.exit(1)


def main(argv=sys.argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        usage(argv)
    config_uri = argv[1]
    options = parse_vars(argv[2:])
    setup_logging(config_uri)
    settings = get_appsettings(config_uri, options=options)

    engine = get_engine(settings)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session_factory = get_session_factory(engine)

    with transaction.manager:
        dbsession = get_tm_session(session_factory, transaction.manager)

        model = MyModel(name='one', value=1)
        dbsession.add(model)
```

And the entrypoints in `setup.py` looks like this:

```
entry_points="""\
  [paste.app_factory]
  main = myproject:main
  [console_scripts]
  initialize_myproject_db = myproject.scripts.initializedb:main
  """,
```

Comment: I spotted that script, but didn't feel great about the boilerplate code. I'll end up using it if necessary, but I'd like to use the simpler bootstrap if possible.